Only show Search Results for Items in my Projects in Solution Explorer while in Debug Mode
I would like the search results in the Solution Explorer to only report on items in my Projects when I am in Debug Mode in Visual Studio.  What are the settings to accomplishing this?
Please up vote this feature here:
Microsoft Feedback Up Vote this feature
I would love for this to get resolved.


Please don't add garbage text to get past our quality filters. If you're prompted to add more detail, add more detail.

I don't believe this is possible. If you'd like this feature, you can suggest it at https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio

Thanks for confirming this is not possible Drew.

Drew, is there an extension that could do what I am asking?  I am new to VS but I am surprised this does not bother anyone.  I often click on the wrong item and it takes me to my GitHub page.  I will make a feature request now.

I discovered CodeSearch by File this week.  This is exactly how I would like Solution Explorer to work.  I do not understand why I cannot dock this Window to the side like the other windows?  What is the reason for this not being dockable?  Perhaps, I am misunderstanding how Microsoft would like us to use this feature.  Thank you

I discovered the solution to my question. I hope this helps others.

Also Disable this.

